# customAdapter how to print out content of array in TextView.setText() of getview

Tags: android

I have written a CustomAdapter to display a list of hash key+value items as a list. But I am stuck on the line below.

label.setText(my_VALUES[0])

Class two is my CustomAdapter and I am passing it a hashMap

```
public MyCustomAdapter(DynamicLists dynamicLists, int row, HashMap<String,String> data)
```

here I combine key+value pairs and I assign them to an array called  my_VALUES. But I don't know if this is correct?

How can I print out each KEY+VALUE pair as a seperate item in getview. at the moment I can only use label.setText(my_VALUES[0])

Thanks

graham 
package gb.org;

```
//lists are not checkboxes 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


//class 1 
public class DynamicLists extends ListActivity { 



//class 2 
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 
    private HashMap<String,String> mData = new HashMap<String,String>();
    private String[] mKeys;
    String[] my_VALUES = new String[100];



    public MyCustomAdapter(DynamicLists dynamicLists, int row, HashMap<String,String> data){ 
    mData = data;
    mKeys = mData.keySet().toArray(new String[data.size()]);
    Log.d(TAG, "INSIDE ADAPTER HELLO WORLD " + map.entrySet()); 


    String[] array = new String[map.size()];
    int count = 0;
    String combined="";
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()){
        combined="A"+entry.getKey()+"B"+entry.getValue();

    my_VALUES[count]=combined;
    Log.d(TAG, " my_VALUES " + my_VALUES);
    count++;


    }


}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String key = mKeys[position];
    String Value = getItem(position).toString();

    //do your view stuff here
    Log.d(TAG, "inside getview  ");
    View row=convertView;

if (row==null){
    LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
    row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
}

TextView label =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.blocked);
label.setText(my_VALUES[0]);  //printing out the last value 

return row;   

}
@Override
public int getCount() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mData.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mData.get(mKeys[position]);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}


}  //end of class 2 



private static final String TAG = "Example";


//class 1 


public static  HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   //tie data to list, call constructor MyCustomAdapter 
   //populate the list. ArrayAdapter takes current class, layout and array
   map.put("year", "Apple");    
   map.put("make", "Mango");     
   map.put("model", "Grape");    
   map.put("style", "Orange");     
   map.put("series", "Peach"); 
   Log.d(TAG, "HELLO WORLD " + map.entrySet());    
   //link to my adapter
   setListAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(DynamicLists.this, R.layout.row, map));

}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
//super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
String selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
Toast.makeText(this, selection, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}


} //end of class 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works.

I only changed 2 things:
1) how my_VALUES is instantiated
2) label.setText(my_VALUES[position]);

```
public class DynamicLists extends ListActivity { 



//class 2 
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 
    private HashMap<String,String> mData = new HashMap<String,String>();
    private String[] mKeys;
    String[] my_VALUES;


    public MyCustomAdapter(DynamicLists dynamicLists, int row, HashMap<String,String> data){ 
    mData = data;

    my_VALUES = new String[mData.size()];


    mKeys = mData.keySet().toArray(new String[data.size()]);
    Log.d(TAG, "INSIDE ADAPTER HELLO WORLD " + map.entrySet()); 


    String[] array = new String[map.size()];
    int count = 0;
    String combined="";
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()){
        combined="A"+entry.getKey()+"B"+entry.getValue();

    my_VALUES[count]=combined;
    Log.d(TAG, " my_VALUES " + my_VALUES);
    count++;


    }


}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String key = mKeys[position];
    String Value = getItem(position).toString();

    //do your view stuff here
    Log.d(TAG, "inside getview  ");
    View row=convertView;

if (row==null){
    LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
    row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
}

TextView label =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.blocked);
label.setText(my_VALUES[position]);  //printing out the last value 

return row;   

}
@Override
public int getCount() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mData.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mData.get(mKeys[position]);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}


}  //end of class 2 



private static final String TAG = "Example";


//class 1 


public static  HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   //tie data to list, call constructor MyCustomAdapter 
   //populate the list. ArrayAdapter takes current class, layout and array
   map.put("year", "Apple");    
   map.put("make", "Mango");     
   map.put("model", "Grape");    
   map.put("style", "Orange");     
   map.put("series", "Peach"); 
   Log.d(TAG, "HELLO WORLD " + map.entrySet());    
   //link to my adapter
   setListAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(DynamicLists.this, R.layout.row, map));

}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
//super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
String selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
Toast.makeText(this, selection, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}


} //end of class 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you are in java just do label.setText(mKeys[position] + getItem(position).toString());